# How to display the facebook request dialog inside our app page?

Tags: facebook

I'm using the facebook request dialog from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ and its working fine.

Now it displays a popup dialog window with the friends of my facebook account.

Now i tried to display the dialog inside my application page itself and i tried to change the display property to 'page' and also 'iframe' and it doesn't seems to be working..

I'm sure that i've initiated the fb using fb:init and it was working fine when i remove the `'display'` property.
How can i do that?

Here's my code..

```
function newInvite(){
   var receiverUserIds = FB.ui({ 
   method : 'apprequests',
   display: 'page',
   //filters: ['app_non_users'],                                  
   message: 'Come on man checkout my new application',
   },
   function(receiverUserIds) {
            //my own callback fun
   }
   );                 
}
```

I've a button for invoking this request and i'm calling this function using jquery as

```
$('#invite_frd').click(function(){      
        newInvite();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

just find the below part in url

```
display=wap
```

and change it to

```
display=touch
```